# I am trying to run the code below but it gives me this error: Trying to get property of non-object in c:\xampp\htdocs\....\index.php on line 47

Tags: php, html

I am trying to execute below code but it gives me an error that 'trying to get property of non-object in c....' .
This code should pull up info about 'images' and 'texts' to be displayed on the index.php page. I have tried in all means but couldn't figure out what is the problem; I am a beginner in PHP by the way :) .I will appreciate if you please help me.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <?php
            $alert = "";

    //if upload button is pressed
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        //the path to store the uploaded image
         $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

         //connect to the database
         $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'imgcms', '', '');

         //Get all the submitted data from thye form
         $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
         $text = $_POST['text'];

         $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, text) VALUES ('$image', '$text')";


         //Move the uploaded image into the folder: images
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
             $alert = "Image uploaded successfully";
         }else{
             $alert = "There was a problem uploading the image";
         }

    }



    ?>

        <html>
    <head>
        <title>ImageBlogger</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        <?php
             //connect to the database to display image from the database
         $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'imgcms', '', '');
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
         $result = $conn->query($sql);

         if($result->num_rows > 0){
             //output data of each row: image and text
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<div id='img_div'>";
                echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."'>";
                echo "<p>".$row['text']."</p>";
             echo "</div>";
         }
    }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();

         ?>

            <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">

                <div>
                <input type="file" name="image">
                </div>

                <div>
                <textarea name="text" cols"40" rows="4" placeholder="Content..."></textarea>
                </div>

                <div>
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Post the content">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying your code into an editor it looks like line 47 is;

```
if($result->num_rows > 0)
```

Before this line add the following and see if you get an error.

```
if (!$result) {
 echo 'Query Error is: ' . $conn->error;}
```

Comment: Hey Rbaskam,
I did add the code and now it says: 'Query error is: No database selected' and the previous error(Trying to get property of non-object...) is still there.

Comment: Your copnnection string on line 43 should be like this. `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` You have no DB name in yours

Comment: I have done that but it still says 'No database selected' plus the previous error. I didn't use password and username for the database by the way when I created the database, so the two fields ($username and $password) remain empty.

Comment: So your connection looks like this then? `new mysqli('localhost', '', '', 'imgcms');` and your database name is imgcms, its also wrong in the connection on line 12

Comment: You could also try `new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'imgcms');` to double check you can actually connect to MySql

Comment: I just edited it to:
 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '   ', 'imgcms');
and now the database looks like is connected, but on my index page it says "0 results"

Comment: No it didn't work
 
I just edited it to: $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'imgcms'); and now the database looks like is connected, but on my index page it says "0 results"

Comment: Ok well its solved the initial issue which was no connection. This means that you need to create a user and give them permissions you require. Or continue using root. How many rows do you have in the table images in the DB imgcms

Comment: it executed the last 'echo' part which says '0 results', so I don't know what's the matter with the while($row.....) code

Comment: This means you have no rows in the table images you are doing `if($result->num_rows > 0)` and its not finding anything. Add some rows to the table images and it should work

Comment: if you mean columns in the database imgcms: i have three columns, id, image, and text

Comment: I guess I have no rows for that case, so what do i do to solve that?

Comment: No you are missing data. As the query `$result->num_rows` is stating  it is looking for rows. So in the DB add a row with an ID, Image and text

Comment: The first part about database connection did work perfectly, so now I think I'm unclear of something: there should be one row created (display on my index.php page ) everytime I click the 'post the content' button, and there should be an image along with text, but I don't see that....can please help on that? by checking my above code?
Sorry though for the double-trouble!

Comment: Is the insert working? Did you change the `$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'imgcms', '', '');` thats in your insert statement to match the working one in the issue you have before. When you run insert then check it goes into the DB.

Comment: Hey brother, sorry I lost internet connection...but everything has worked as I wanted....
All I had to do was adding this line: mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
Below the '$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, text) VALUES ('$image', '$text')";' line. Thank you so much for helping me through this!